# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown multiple instance

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

I have two bootstrap multiselect dropdown in a page. Whenever i click on "select all" checkbox in one dropdown the "select all" checkbox from other dropdown gets checked. Don't know how to solve this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved with the help of this https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/751

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `<select>` elements may have the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

its old question but i think it might help someone 
you just have to pass different class or id to the list thats get generated .
for example in bootstrap-multiple.js file there is one element named :  `buttonContainer: '','
you can change this while you call the multiselect like this :

```
    $('#idofthefirstselectelement').multiselect({
                buttonContainer: '<div class="btn-group pull-right" id="whateveridyouwish" />',
            });
$('#idofthesecondselectelement').multiselect({
                buttonContainer: '<div class="btn-group pull-right" id="whateveridyouwish" />',


            });
```

and in your datatable preparation method append/attach it like this

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                    $('#idoffirstmaindiv .dt-buttons').append($('#whateveridyouwish'));
                },
```